# How to keep track of my internal frames?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jinternalframe

This example code is a short version of my actual program:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Example extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTable table;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Example frame = new Example();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Example() {
    //what to do @ close
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 792, 585);

    //content pane
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    //create desktop pane add it to content pane
    final JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
    contentPane.add(desktopPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //create Int Frame with table
    JInternalFrame tableIntFrame = new JInternalFrame("TableIntFrame");
    tableIntFrame.setBounds(31, 29, 300, 205);
    desktopPane.add(tableIntFrame);

    //create the table
    table = new JTable();

    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[][] {
            {"Row 0 (click for more info)"},
            {"Row 1 (click for more info)"},
        },
        new String[] {
            "Collumn 0"
        }
    ));

    //add the table to a ScrollPane
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    //add Scrollpane to table       
    tableIntFrame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    tableIntFrame.setVisible(true);

    //Listen for events on selection
    table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new
            ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

            // only fires ones
            if (! e.getValueIsAdjusting())
            { 
                //create info frame with title set to selectedrow index
                createFrame(desktopPane, table.getSelectedRow()+"");

            }

        }
    });
    // Allow only one row to be selected.
    table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);



}

//Creates an int frame with the title set to the row
private void createFrame(JDesktopPane desktopPane, String selectedRow){

    JInternalFrame InfoIntFrame = new JInternalFrame("Info Row "+selectedRow);
    InfoIntFrame.setBounds(425, 44, 183, 72);
    //add to desktop
    desktopPane.add(InfoIntFrame);
    //set visible
    InfoIntFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

How do I get it to work for that clicking a row when it's corresponding infoIntFrame is already open doesn't create another instance of infoIntframe? (note: The infoIntFrames have to be created at runtime)

Comment: You won't create a new FrameListIntFrame after the first one because you check to make sure that it's not null.  It looks like you are only entering that if statement once.

Comment: it could be nice question, please edit your post with a http://sscce.org/

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2741726/230513) cites an example that uses `Action` to track multiple internal frames.

Comment: @mKorbel I have edited my question. I added an simple example of the problem. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two areas:

1) `JInternalFrame tableIntFrame = new JInternalFrame("TableIntFrame");` lost Focus

2) you have to check if exist in array that returns [desktopPane.getAllFrames()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDesktopPane.html#getAllFrames%28%29) before creating new another [JInternalFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html), add [InternalFrameListener,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/internalframelistener.html) because (AFAIK) method desktopPane.getAllFrames() returns only visible `JInternalFrame`