# In FrameView is not showing JDesktopPane and JinternalFrame on Windows OS

Tags: java, windows, swing, netbeans, jsr296

Im using netbeans 6.9 and ubuntu. I make a Simple Java Desktop Application thas cames with netbeans wizard.
Then when I tried to run on linux the jdesktoppane show me on the bottom of my application all the opened jinternalframe, but when i run on windows xp o windows 7 then jdesktoppane is not showing.
Here are the images to understand a little bit the problem. On Skydrive all the image http ://sdrv.ms/KSX2cw

The Netbeans configuration of FrameView. Here you could see the properties of the FrameView that I change the component to the JDesktopPane.

This is the app running on linux. All JInternalFrame are show on the JDesktopPane bar.
Here is the image on Skydrive to see: 
http://sdrv.ms/MJz2T0

And this is the app running on Windows 7 (or Windows XP too). Here is not showing the JInteralFrame opened.
Here is the image on Skydrive to see: 
http://sdrv.ms/MJzdh5

I do not made any other change to code rather than add the JInternalFrame.

Finally Where is JDesktopPane with the JInternalFrame opened on Windows OS?

Comment: *"I do not made any other change to code.."*  Since you mention it, what is it?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). & try and reproduce it with `JFrame` rather than some unsupported API (AFAIR `FrameView`).

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans has since [dropped support](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic46715.html) for [jsr296](/questions/tagged/jsr296). This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513) may guide you going forward, and [*How to Use Internal Frames*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) may be helpful. More examples may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8090328/230513), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9414728/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2741726/230513).