# Adding a Form to Swing Menu application

Tags: java, swing, menu, jframe

I am writing a Swing Menu based application. In the Menu I have File->New->Add Person
Here Add Person is a form and the new option will have many other forms.
When I click on any of this form it has to be added to the menu display area.

My question is how do I add it to the display area. should the display area already consist of any swing container to which I can add my Forms?

Also, note that each of these Forms that I have created are individual JFrames

Answer (score 3):

> Also, note that each of these Forms that I have created are individual JFrames

- never to use lots of `JFrames`, this is road to the hell

> My question is how do I add it to the display area. should the display area already consist of any swing container to which I can add my Forms?

- if you need popup window then to use `JDialog`, only one `JDialog` and re_use that for another action

> I am writing a Swing Menu based application. In the Menu I have File->New->Add Person Here Add Person is a form and the new option will have many other forms. When I click on any of this form it has to be added to the menu display area.

- use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for swithing betweens views

Answer (score 2):

You can go with the `JInternalFrame` option. It helps you to do your requirement, refer the links,

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html

Also refer this link for examples,

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/InterestingthingsusingJInternalFramesJDesktopPaneandDesktopManager2.htm

Comment: An related example connecting internal frames & menus is cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741036/using-jinternalframe-and-some-jbutton/2741726#2741726).

Answer (score 0):

U can Display JFrame Forms on Click of Menu on Top of Parent Window.
U can make it act like a dialog by making the Parent Form disable and when Child Form Exits again we can Enable the parent Form.

Comment: I am able to do that but I am not looking for the option, I want to display that in the Main window itself

Comment: U can make ur Forms on JPanel and load it on the Main Forms Container. or u can Use JInternalFrame.

Comment: This works.
Will you have an idea as to why a JFrame does not work in place of JPanel??

Comment: @AlwinDoss *"why a JFrame does not work in place of JPanel??"* See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: @AlwinDoss U cannot add External JFrame inside a Frame. u have to use JInternalFrame.