# ActionListener in InternalFrame that opens another InternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem

I'm currently writing a Desktop-Application with Swing that consists of a `MainFrame` in which several `InternalFrames` will be running. I want to write the `InternalFrames` in separate classes for each to avoid having one huge `MainFrame`-class.

Now my problem is that I want to add an `ActionListener` to a `MenuItem` in a `PopupMenu` in the `MenuInternalFrame` that opens another `InternalFrame` in the `MainFrame`. The `MenuInternalFrame` appears, however when I click on the MenuItem nothing happens. When I put the code outside of the `ActionListener` the InternalFrame appears.

The problem must be something with the `ActionListener`. Could it be my workaround with the local class and a final instance to access the `InternalFrame` from within the `mouseClicked`-Method?

Here are the relevant parts of the code from the `MainFrame`-Constructor:

```
class InternalFrames {
    TestInternalFrame test = new TestInternalFrame();
    JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
}

final InternalFrames internalFrames = new InternalFrames();

internalFrames.desktopPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

Menu menu = new Menu();
menu.getMntmTestMenuItem().addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        internalFrames.desktopPane.add(internalFrames.test);
        internalFrames.test.setVisible(true);
    }
});
internalFrames.desktopPane.add(menu);
menu.setVisible(true);
```

Any ideas what could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use `MouseAdapter` on a `JMenuItem`, use `ActionListener` and add it via `JMenuItem#addActionListener(...)` instead:

```
Menu menu = new Menu();
menu.getMntmTestMenuItem().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            internalFrames.desktopPane.add(internalFrames.test);
            internalFrames.test.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know that you couldn't use MouseListener in this context.

Comment: Also consider `Action`, suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2741726/230513).

Comment: @trashgod what are the reasons for using `Action` over `AbstractAction` or `ActionListener`?

Comment: Increased [flexibility](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11944233/230513).